# Symfony2 Error when overriding bundle template "resource is hidden by a resource"?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to override a third party bundle's layout template with the layout of my bundle, by including the new layout in the app/Resources/ directory as indicated in the [Symfony2 book section](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates); however, I'm getting the following exception:

> "...path_to_my_app/app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig" resource is hidden by a resource from the "MyVendorMyBundle" derived bundle. Create a "...path_to_my_app/app/Resources/MyVendorMyBundle/views/layout.html.twig" file to override the bundle resource.

In particular, I would like to overwrite the FOSUserBundle layout with that in my bundle. I followed the steps shown in the [bundle's documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md), which are no different than those in the Symfony book.

**What could be the cause of this exception? and how can I make it work?**

I tried putting my bundle's layout in the app/Resources/MyVendorMyBundle/views/ as indicated in the above exception message, but if I do that, only the layout of MyBundle is read and returned and not the templates for the FOSUserBundle that extend it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the developer that preceded me had set MyBundle as a child of FOSUserBundle as [shown in the documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md) (without me noticing...):

```
// src/Acme/UserBundle/AcmeUserBundle.php
namespace Acme\UserBundle;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AcmeUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

The above was obviously creating conflict with (hiding) the re-defined layout template in the app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/ folder. I just deleted the getParent() method from the above shown bundle class to solve the issue.